# Showing/Hiding button from firefox extension not working on specific web page

Tags: javascript, jquery, browser-extension

I am writing a simple browser extension to my web app.

I have a list with cards `<ul id="cards-in-progress">` on my website and I want to use the extension to add an attribute to that ul tag hiding or showing it.

On my extension I have the following buttons on the popup.html:

```
<h3 class="lead">Hide Cards</h3>
    <div class="input-group mb-3 has-success">
        <div class="input-group-append">
            <button id="hideAllCards" class="btn btn-success" type="button" data-toggle="popover" data-placement="top" data-content="Hide all cards">
                Hide
            </button>
        </div>
    </div>
    </p>

    <p>
        <h3 class="lead">Show Cards</h3>
        <div class="input-group mb-3 has-success">
            <div class="input-group-append">
                <button id="showAllCardsButton" class="btn btn-success" type="button" data-toggle="popover" data-placement="top" data-content="Show all cards">
                    Show
                </button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </p>
```

On my extension, I have the popup.js:

```
$("#hideAllCards").click(function() {
    $('#cards-in-progress').attr("style", "display: none !important");
});

$("#showAllCardsButton").click(function()  {
    $('#cards-in-progress').attr("style", "display: block !important");
});
```

PS.: I am using it on firefox
PS.: I have a JS folder with jquery.js and popup.js

What am I actually doing wrong?

## UPDATE

When I try to use alert(), usually the alert box should appear on the website and not on my HTML extension. What is happening at the moment is that alert() is being executed on my extension.
It means that the code I am trying to execute is not being sent to my website but it remains on my extension. I can't figure why.

[image]

Comment: You want to show and hide `<ul id="cards-list">` and using different id on button click ?

Comment: My bad, sorry. I updated the question, but it still does not work. Thank you for pointing it out though

Comment: is you ul hiding ?

Comment: no, it is not hiding. I checked on the devtools and the class is not being inserted on the webpage.

Comment: It will not add class, it add css property only

Comment: do you have jquery on your extension ?

Comment: I know. I am trying to add the style property on the html like I used to do but it did not work.

Comment: I have a jquery file on the same folder where my popup.js is

Comment: You still have different selectors in your click-functions. And poss. a typo. Maybe it should be `'#draggableheader'`

Comment: Have you tested deleget event? `$("#hideAllCards").on('click',function() {
      $('#cards-in-progress').attr("style", "display: none !important");
   });`

Comment: changed as suggested but it doesnt work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To manipulate the tab I had to change my function as it follows:

```
const hideCards = `#cards-in-progress {
    display: none;
}`;

  $("#hideAllCards").on('click',function() { browser.tabs.insertCSS({code: hideCards}) });

  $("#showAllCardsButton").on('click',function() { browser.tabs.removeCSS({code: hideCards}) });
```